# Can Obama put extra checks at this stage, on America's nuclear weaponry, with a Trump Presidency?

Tags: united-states, president, nuclear-weapons

I don't know what that would involve, maybe making the command 3 or 4 leveled rather than the current 2. Well what can be done at this stage to secure America's nuclear weaponry, when the perception of some people is that the next president can be uncertain at times.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Obama is the current POTUS.

Barring something outside the normal political process<sup>1</sup>, Trump will be the next POTUS.

The power of these men depends of their position. Any changes the current POTUS can enact, the next POTUS can dispose of.

The only way to avoid it would be from somehow change the constitutional roles of the POTUS, and that kind of reform is not something that can be done overnight ever if there was legislative support for it (and there is not). And again, if Trump did have the legislative support to undo those changes, he could revert them.

As much as someone might despise Trump personally, any attempt to block him for getting the full responsabilities as a POTUS will be way more damaging to democracy and the USA than a Trump presidency itself (or at least let's hope so).

And let's not forget that, as @Sejanus comments, there are many people who believe that he is the right person for these responsabilities and, in a democracy, the value of each opinion is supposed to matter the same<sup>2</sup>.

So, for anyone worried, stop looking for "special solutions" and begin working in the regular solutions (raising public awareness, public speech -including peaceful protests-, etc.)

Again, the power of the government is not only in the POTUS but also in Congress and the Supreme Court, the President has some power but there are "checks and balances".

---

<sup>1</sup>And let me be clear, outside events affecting the normal political process are by themselves a very BAD thing, no matter the outcome.

<sup>2</sup>Yes I know, popular vote vs electoral college, but there are already lots of answers covering that.

Comment: When did this become a site for partisan banter?   @SJuan76 gave a nice answer.   If you have something constrictive to add, then you can comment.

Comment: @userTLK: constructive not constrictive.

Comment: @userLTK I'm guessing it was about the same time when an extremely partisan, controversial, and unconventional Presidential election ended in an extremely partisan and unconventional way (and arguably controversial, depending on how you view the electoral college, and all the alleged shenanigans with voter rights that always come up).  As for the answer's checks and balances, it gets a little strained to say these are protecting things when the majority of voters go for democratic candidates yet Republicans have majorities in both houses, the presidency, and de facto control of the judicial.